# Help with simple limit calculation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have tried searching the site for an answer but I couldnt find any even though it's a simple calculation.

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{4^n + 7^n}{4^{n-1} + 7^{n-1}}\right) $$

Thanks , Danny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{4^n + 7^n}{4^{n-1} + 7^{n-1}}\right)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{7^n}{7^{n-1}} \left( \frac{(\frac{4}{7})^n+1}{(\frac{4}{7})^{n-1}+1} \right)=7 \frac{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \left( (\frac{4}{7})^n+1 \right)}{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \left( (\frac{4}{7})^{n-1}+1 \right)}$$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{4}{7})^n=0, \quad \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{4}{7})^{n-1}=0$$
So
$$7 \frac{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \left( (\frac{4}{7})^n+1 \right)}{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \left( (\frac{4}{7})^{n-1}+1 \right)}=7.\frac{(0+1)}{(0+1)}=7$$

Comment: Some care is due here: in the middle step in the last line, you pass to the limit in part of the expression (the one inside parentheses in both numerator and denominator), while the other part is left untouched. This is wrong, and in other cases it can easily take us to pretty wrong results. You can pass with *the whole thing* to the limit and you get just the same, or *separate* the factors justifying by arithmetic of limits as both parts' limits exist finitely.

Comment: Thanks DonAntonio for pointing this out. One should know what one is doing even if it is not stated explicitly. Also the problem could be avoided if we factored out $7^{n - 1}$ from the numerator and denominator.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks.